# .htaccess Redirect results in a redirect loop

Tags: server, apache2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So on my site, my shopping cart is located at `example.com/zc2`.

I use this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect /index.html https://example.com/zc2/
```

So that anyone that lands on `example.com` will be redirected to my shopping cart.

All good, but now if I try and install WordPress at `example.com/wp` then browsers get stuck in a redirect loop.

I am positive it is my badly crafted `.htaccess` file.

**What can I do to fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Redirect /index.html https://example.com/zc2/
> ```

`Redirect` is a mod_alias directive, not mod_rewrite, and has nothing to do with the `RewriteEngine` directive (which enables the mod_rewrite rewriting engine) that precedes it.

However, whilst the `Redirect` directive in the root `.htaccess` file is likely to *conflict* with other `.htaccess` files (eg. WordPress), it's not clear why this would specifically trigger a redirect loop. (You should observe the network traffic to see exactly the nature of this "loop".)

However, you can minimise conflicts by changing this rule to use mod_rewrite instead. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ https://example.com/zc2 [R,L]
```

Any mod_rewrite directives in child `.htaccess` files (eg. `/wp/.htaccess`) will completely override this directive in the root `.htaccess` file (by default).